# How to store SSH key without attempting to login with password using Plink?

Tags: windows, ssh, unix

The below command is used to attempt to store the SSH key, even though we tried to force exit in the command, still it is asking password.

```
echo y | plink -ssh root@172.19.117.69 "exit".

The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.

The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 a8:8a:f6:67:b4:42:03:09:ae:4b:57:ff:85:c0:94:bf
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.

Store key in cache? (y/n) 
root@172.19.117.69's password:
```

Answer (score 0):

Fingerprint and Key-authentication are 2 different stories.

```
echo y | plink -ssh root@172.19.117.69 "exit".
```

Should avoid that the next time the "Store key in cache? (y/n)" question to occur.
You must generate an authentication key to use plink without a password for your server.